# Change entity manager dynamically in codeception when cleanup=true

Tags: doctrine-orm, entitymanager, codeception

I am using Cest classes for unit test and I have one test class per entity where I perform some tests that can read/write records to/from the database.

I use PostgreSQL where entities can be part of different schema, so Entity1 is part of Schema1, which uses EntityManager1 while Entity2 is part of Schema2 and uses EntityManager2.

Each Cest class defines Doctrin2 module's $em entity in _before method before starting the test and it works fine.

When I set cleanup=true to encapsulate tests in transaction, it fails to clean (rollback transaction), because during initialization codeception runs Doctrin2 module's _before method first, where transaction is set per initial/current entity manager. When I change entity manager in the Cest, then initial entity manager is not able to track those changes that are happening in different entity manager and it thinks that nothing to roll back at the end of the test.

```
# unit.suite.yml
modules:
enabled: [Symfony2, Doctrine2, Asserts, UnitHelper]
config:
      Doctrine2:
          cleanup: true
```

I can start my own transaction in the Cest as nested transaction, but it's against DRY principle. It is possible to initialize proper entity manager in the _bootstrap file, but it won't be dynamic and I dont know how to change it there based on which Cest is running.

Is it possible to change entity manager before running Doctrin2 module's _before method? Maybe there is no need to use any manipulation at all and all this can be achieved by some other setup (like test suit per entity, etc.)?